# CentOS live CD of current installation

Tags: linux, backup, livecd, centos-5

I'm trying to create a live CD of my current CentOS installation. I want it to be almost like a backup, so whenever I want to copy my current installation to another computer I would simply install from my custom live CD.

I know this is possible, and I found some resources on the net, but they all seem to only create a minimal version of CentOS; I want to have all the current functionalities available to me at present, including all of my development functionalities, Apache and samba settings, etc.

I did this on Debian a few years ago, but I can't remember how.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following guide on creating LiveCD's http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/LiveCDHowTo

But....

Why not use a liveUSB instead of liveCD? This would allow you to rsync settings and config files across to a single USB pen (through the use of persistent storage on the device). It would save CD's after all ;)

[image]

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo